# C++ Threads - Crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, crash

For the whole day I'm trying to find the solution, without any result. You're the only hope.

I have to do sound synthesizer based on bass.h library. Everything worked fine until I wanted it to play separate streams. I decided to do it on separate threads:

```
void Synthezator::play(MonoStream *stream1, MonoStream *stream2)
{
    threadParam data = {stream1, this};
    threadParam data2 = {stream2, this};
    int x = 6;
    DWORD threadId;
    DWORD threadId2;
    //thread first (PlayThread, data);
    //thread second (PlayThread, data2);
    //first.join();
    //second.join();
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, PlayThread, (PVOID) &data, 0, &threadId);
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, PlayThread, (PVOID) &data2, 0, &threadId2);
    getchar();  
}
```

(commented ones works in the same way)

The crashes occures randomly (in random moments, not every time) only if two threads are working. If I comment one of them - there's no crash.

PlayThread function:

```
DWORD WINAPI Synthezator::PlayThread(PVOID data)
{
    //cout << "kurwa";
    int i=0;
    threadParam* dataNew = (threadParam*) data;
    dataNew->stream->SeekBegin();
    while(!(dataNew->stream->eof()))
    {
        int no = 0;
        note* a = dataNew->stream->Next(&no);
        dataNew->pointer->PlayNote(a, no);
        i++;
    }
}
```

PlayNote:

```
void Synthezator::PlayNote(note* note, int count)
{
    position = new double[count];
    generatorParams params = {synthType, count, note, position, this};
    HSTREAM SignalStream = BASS_StreamCreate (FREQUENCY, 1, 0, &Generator, &params);
    if (SignalStream == 0) throw " Cannot create stream";

    if(note->sound != 0) {
        if (!BASS_ChannelPlay (SignalStream, TRUE)) throw "Cannot play generated sample";
    }
    const int secinusecs = 1000000;
        sleep(secinusecs*floor(note->duration)/1000000);
        usleep(secinusecs*(note->duration-floor(note->duration)));
    if(note->sound != 0) {
        BASS_ChannelStop(SignalStream);
    }
    BASS_StreamFree(SignalStream);
    delete [] position; 
}
```

If I comment this line, there's no crash (but also there's no sound):

```
if (!BASS_ChannelPlay (SignalStream, TRUE)) throw "Cannot play generated sample";
```

Comment: Judging by the first cout in PlayThread You have been struggling with this for a while :D

Comment: Where is position variable declared? It is modified from 2 threads at the same time!

Comment: Removing line "delete [] position;" solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: No it did NOT - You now have a memory leak (the memory is allocated and no one frees it)!

Comment: `threadParam data` and `threadParam data2` are local variables in play(). When play ends these will no longer be valid. So if your thread accesses them after play finished you will have UB. Although I guess that is the point of getchar().

Comment: Good catch dreshcerjm. I missed that when I skimmed it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the threads:

```
threadParam data = {stream1, this};
threadParam data2 = {stream2, this};
CreateThread(NULL, 0, PlayThread, (PVOID) &data, 0, &threadId);
CreateThread(NULL, 0, PlayThread, (PVOID) &data2, 0, &threadId2);
```

Inside the thread

```
dataNew->pointer->PlayNote(a, no);
```

The problem is that you are using the same objects PlayNote function from two different locations. Thus before thread 1 completes PlayNote, thread 2 comes into PlayNote. The first thing in PlayNote is dynamic memory allocation stored within the object, so thread 2 just trashed thread 1's pointer. At which point thread 1's behavior becomes undetermined and a crash is guaranteed to happen once the other thread switches back into contex after the first thread completes the function and deletes the pointer.

Welcome to multithreaded programming. Here's your hat.

Comment: I'm not editing those object, so I don't understand why I should not use them. Anyway, removing line "delete [] position;" fixed the problem.

Comment: You ARE editing the object within PlayNote when you modify position. And by removing the delete you have introduced a memory leak and will cause in-deterministic behavior when the crash would have otherwise occurred. Making position local to PlayNote, leaving in the delete is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the `position` member is the only member You modify in different threads then I suggest You to put back the `delete [] position;` line and declare position as private variable: `double* position = new double[count];`

This way each thread will have its own position array.

Although I have to see the whole code to be certain that other members are not modified by multiple threads.